# remove duplicate entry from file1 if entry present in file2

Tags: awk

I want to delete duplicate entry *e* from `file1` if *e* is also present in `file2`.

Input `file1`:

```
x1  y1
x2  y2
x3  y3
x4  y4
y1  x1
x5  y5
y3  x3
x6  y6
x5  y5
```

Input `file2`:

```
y1  x1
y2  x2
y3  x3
y4  x4
x1  y1
y5  x5
x3  y3
y6  x6
x5  y5
```

Desired output:

```
x1  y1
x2  y2
x3  y3
x4  y4
x5  y5
x6  y6
```

I have used following shell script:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {

   lines[NR,"col1"] = $1
   lines[NR,"col2"] = $2
   lines[NR,"line"] = $0
   next
    }

  (lines[FNR,"col1"] != $1) {($1 in lines)
    print lines[FNR,"line"]
    next
}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

But it is giving following output:

```
x1  y1
x2  y2
x3  y3
x4  y4
y1  x1
x5  y5
y3  x3
x6  y6
```

Comment: `x1 y1` appears in both files?

Answer (score 2):

First : your desired output should be :

```
y2  x2
y4  x4
y5  x5
y6  x6
```

because "x3 y3" and "x1 y1" are present in the both files

to get lines that are present in file1 only you can simply do

```
grep -v -f file1 file2
```

From man page

```
-v
--invert-match
 Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines. (-v is specified by POSIX.)

-f file
   --file=file
Obtain patterns from file, one per line. The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing. (-f is specified by POSIX.)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk '{if($1>$2) print $2 "  " $1; else print $0;}' file1.txt file2.txt | sort -u > out.txt
```

this will output:

```
x1  y1
x2  y2
x3  y3
x4  y4
x5  y5
x6  y6
```

`awk` simply reorders columns by alphabetical order, `sort -u` (unique) removes duplicated lines.